# How to include only part of an entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have this linq query which works just fine.

```
 var items  = this._context.History.Where(a => a.ItemId == id).Include(a=> a.AppUser.ApplicationUser).ToList();
```

But, there is an issue. The `ApplicationUser` is included in order to get the `FirstName` and `LastName` of the user.  But the rest of the table is not needed.

The real issue is that since the `ApplicationUser` is now in the Context, a completely different query which does NOT include the `ApplicationUser`, ends up with the `ApplicationUser` being populated and sent to the client (out-security).

```
 this.DbSet.Where(a => a.EntityStatusId == (int)EntityStatus.Enum.Active && a.ItemId == entityId ).Include(a=> a.AppUser).ToList();
```

But all I really need is `ApplicationUser.FirstName`, and `ApplicationUser.LastName` from this table.

The only workaround I can think of is to create a new `Context()` for the one query, but that seems to violate the D.I. pattern being used. No changes need to be saved, it's just getting data for display.

Comment: Why not returning a DTO for each query?

Comment: @CodeNotFound Can you give me an example?

Comment: You create DTO class that will contains only properties you want and you use the class to project EF result to it.

Comment: *"it's just getting data for display*" Then create a class containing just the data needed for display (a.k.a. ViewModel, DTO etc.) and use projection query (`Select`) to populate it. Entity classes and eager loading are for representing the full table record data (not partial queries).

Comment: @CodeNotFound, I got that working.  If you want to post as answer, I will accept.

Comment: You might also want to look into `.AsNoTracking()` if you want to explicitly tell your context not to keep track of entities you retrieve. It can have performance increases in certain situations as well.